How to get authorized user's email and how to sign out the authorized user using Google Identity in android?
I am calling requestGoogleDriveAuthorization() method for a button click listener and authorize a user.
private val authorizationResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data = result.data
            handleAuthorizationResult(data)
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Authorization failed or canceled")
        }
    }

    private fun requestGoogleDriveAuthorization() {
        val requestedScopes = listOf(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY))
        val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
            .build()

        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(requireContext())
            .authorize(authorizationRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
                if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                    val pendingIntent = authorizationResult.pendingIntent
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Start intent sender")
                        val intentSenderRequest = pendingIntent?.let { IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it.intentSender).build() }
                        authorizationResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start Authorization UI: " + e.localizedMessage)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Making GDrive client with access token: ${authorizationResult.accessToken}")
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val credential = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(authorizationResult.accessToken, null))
                        GDriveClient.makeDriveBuilder(credential = credential)
                        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            GDriveClient.googleCredentialToken = authorizationResult.accessToken
                        }
                    }

                    startActivity(Intent(this.requireActivity(), TracksDownloadActivity::class.java).apply {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Access token before activity starts: ${GDriveClient.googleCredentialToken}")
                        putExtra("signInOption", "googleDrive")
                    })
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to authorize", e)
            }
    }

    private fun handleAuthorizationResult(data: Intent?) {
        val authorizationResult: AuthorizationResult = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(
            requireContext()
        ).getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(data)
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside handleAuthorizationResult")
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val credential = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(authorizationResult.accessToken, null))
            GDriveClient.makeDriveBuilder(credential = credential)
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                GDriveClient.googleCredentialToken = authorizationResult.accessToken
            }
        }

        startActivity(Intent(this.requireActivity(), TracksDownloadActivity::class.java).apply {
            Log.d(TAG, "Access token before activity starts: ${GDriveClient.googleCredentialToken}")
            putExtra("signInOption", "googleDrive")
        })
    }

I have done the user's authorization successfully and retrieved data from user's drive. But I can not find any way to extract the authorized user's email. Also couldn't find a way to sign out the authorized user.
I want to know how to get the authorized user's email and how can I sign out the already authorized user from my app?

Pro tip:
The about.get method in google drive returns the users email address.  I cant help with Kotlin but make sure you add fields=* to the request as an alternate parm to get everything back
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json

This returns an About response which contains a user object which has their email address.
